# Excel - Search a word in Column A. When a match is found in the row, report the word that is in Column B, then search column A for any reported words

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I want to know how to search for a string in Column A, report the corresponding string(s) that are found in Column B, and then search column A again for those reported string(s), etc. Repeat till no more matches are found.

I am trying to create a user friendly sheet or macro-Input-Box that will search a 2300+ line Excel sheet and generate a report.  I want the user to be able to select the “string” that will be searched (I will do this with a drop down menu).  The sheet/program will then:

1. search Column A for all matches to the selected string;
2. report the corresponding string(s) that is(are) found in Column B (same row as a match);
3. search Column A again for all reported strings that were found in Column B;
4. repeat steps 2) and 3) until no more matches are found.

Currently a simple filter is used on Columns A and B.  The user first selects the string they wish to filter in Column A.  They must then manually determine if any of the results in Column B are present in Column A and, if so, add them to the filtering criteria of column A.  In some cases this can require multiple iterations of this process and can become quite time consuming.

My goal is to remove the need for the user to have to manually go through these iterations.

Here is a simplified version of what I am looking at (the actual names are more complex).

```
Equipment   Contents

Box 1       Box 2
Box 1       Box 3
Box 1       Box 4
Box 1       Tool 1
Box 1       Tool 2
Box 1       Tool 3
Box 2       Box 5
Box 2       Tool 4
Box 2       Tool 5
Box 3       Box 6
Box 3       Tool 6
Box 3       Tool 7
Box 4       Tool 8
Box 5       Tool 9
Box 6       Tool 10
```

For example “Box 2” contains “Box 5”, “Tool 4”, and “Tool 5”.  “Box 5” contains “Tool 9”.  So, if the user selects “Box 2”, the report would generate a four-row report; “Box 5”, “Tool 4”, “Tool 5”, and “Tool 9” (not necessarily in this order).

I began this task, thinking that I could use a simple index-match code in a hidden sheet and then report the significant values on a user sheet.  Here is the code I was using to search the first column and retrieve the results from the second (note the references do not correspond to the sample sheet above):

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('All Inclusive Tab'!D:F,SMALL(IF('All Inclusive Tab'!D:D=$A$2,ROW('All Inclusive Tab'!D:D)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX('All Inclusive Tab'!D:F,SMALL(IF('All Inclusive Tab'!D:D=$A$2,ROW('All Inclusive Tab'!D:D)),ROW(1:1)),2))`

I have inputted this code into multiple cells on a separate sheet.  Other cells on the sheet contain similar code, which then searches for the values that are reported by this code. Etc.  This method works at finding multiple matches. However, I have found it is limited due to the complexity of my Excel sheet (especially given the large number of line items).  It is also very slow once I start creating multiple “working” cells.  I am certain there must be a better way to do this.

I was told to create a macro and use a “for” or “while” loop.  I am not very familiar with VBA and am looking for any suggestions.  What search codes would be useful for this application and how would they be parsed?  I am also toying with the idea of doing this project using Microsoft Access, and am wondering if that would make things easier or more complex.

EDIT: Here are two examples of the desired output.  If "Box 2" was selected from the drop down, the output would look like such:

```
Equipment   Contents
Box 2       Box 5
Box 5       Tool 9
Box 2       Tool 4
Box 2       Tool 5
```

And if "Box 3" were selected from the drop down, the output would look like such:

```
Equipment   Contents
Box 3       Box 6
Box 6       Tool 10
Box 3       Tool 6
Box 3       Tool 7
```

Comment: You can create a **recursive function** that **loops** through the cells in Column A. With each match, it will call the same function to lookup the contained item in the list. The matched value will return and can be appended to a **delimited string**. I've bolded some terms to help you get started.

Comment: Access would be different, I wouldn't say harder. You could use **SQL** and **join the table to itself**, then **update the WHERE clause with VBA**.

Comment: Do you plan on users returning to a given item after the listing has been generated? How often will the listing change? How do you want to display the results to the user?

Comment: Thanks DiegoAndresJAY. The listing should not change too frequently, however changes will be made maybe every 6 months.  I want the results to be displayed in a table format (similar to excel).  I would want the user to be able to run a search through column A.  Then after a report is generated, they could run a seperate search on the same column.

Answer (score 0):

For this example I set It up like this,

[image]

When the code is run, the results will be like this.
[image]

Here is the code.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rws As Long, rng As Range, c As Range, Frng As Range, Frws As Long
    Range("K:Z").ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("K1"), Unique:=True
    rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("K3:K" & rws)
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        Columns("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=c
        Frws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Frng = Range("B3:B" & Frws).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Frng.Copy
        c.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
                                    False, Transpose:=True
    Next c
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = 0
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The results are not exactly how I would like them to be displayed.  I have edited my above question and given two examples of how I would like the search results to be displayed.  How could I modify your search to display the results in this manner?